# findBy with multiple IDs

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

In my quest to edit data from the inverse side of a `ManyToOne - OneToMany` relation, and to avoid fetching the whole table's content, I want to fetch data from a list of IDs.

While this would work,

```
$data=array();
foreach($idList as $id) {
    array_push($data, $em->getRepository(Entity::class)->findBy(array('id', $id)));
}
```

It would do as many queries as there are IDs.
Before making my own query in the repository, I would like to know if it's possible to use multiple IDs with `findBy`.

If it's possible, how do I do it?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can do

```
$em->getRepository(Entity::class)->findBy(array('id' => $idList));
```

Comment: Oh... was as simple as this... I simply assumed that it wasn't possible that way... Thanks

Comment: It wasn't until pretty recently.

Comment: @Preciel the documentation sucks, however this is at least vaguely documented here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions `If you pass an array of values Doctrine will convert the query into a WHERE field IN (..) query automatically:`

Comment: I receive the error `Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister::getSelectConditionStatementColumnSQL(): Argument #1 ($field) must be of type string, int given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/src/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php on line 165`