# Doctrine findBy array of UUIDs

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine, uuid

I'm having a problem retrieving users by UUIDs using Doctrine in my Symfony application, and after a few hours of struggling without any real leads, I decided to ask the question here in case I missed something obvious.

Problem:
I have a Symfony application where users are identified by UUIDs.I'm trying to retrieve users from a list of UUIDs using Doctrine's findBy method, but I systematically get an empty array even though the UUIDs exist in the database.

Here my $id field:

```php
trait UuidTrait
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: UuidType::NAME, unique: true)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: 'doctrine.uuid_generator')]
    private ?Uuid $id = null;

    public function getId(): ?Uuid
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

My Code to retrieve users:

```php
$ids = ["018dd095-4c15-78b4-8f45-6c0bdc78368e","018dd226-5561-7b24-8677-64fa33a0267b"];
$users = $userRepository->findBy(["id" => $ids]); // -> empty array
```

I tried to convert my strings to UUIDs with:

```php
$ids = array_map(fn (string $id) => Uuid::fromString($id), $ids);
```

But it still didn't work...

I checked my ids:

```php
$users = $userRepository->findBy(["id" => $ids[0]]);
```

And $users contained 1 user so my ids were good.

The worst thing is that there are no errors thrown so I don't know where the problem is. I've seen several people use an array as a criteria parameter ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52426917/findby-with-multiple-ids)) so I assumed it was working.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Geod

EDIT: Is saw [this](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions) in the doctrine documentation and my code looks correct

Comment: What type is your $userRepository? Because the only thing I can see logically with your code vs the examples you give, is that the examples use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository class to call the findBy method on. They use the EntityManager to fetch the Repository, and then call the findBy method on that. Check your types.

Comment: `class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository implements PasswordUpgraderInterface`
Is this what you're asking for ?

Comment: I just tried:
`$entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findBy(["id" => $ids])`
But unfortunatly it's not work....

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Doctrine might not be able to handle a list of UUIDs all at once. So, I've come up with a solution to handle this situation. Hopefully, it works for you!

```
public function fetchByUuids(array $uuids){

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');
    $expr = $qb->expr()->orX();
    foreach ($uuids as $key => $uuid) {
        $paramName = 'id_' . $key;
        $expr->add($qb->expr()->eq('m.id', ':' . $paramName));
        $qb->setParameter($paramName, $uuid, UuidType::NAME);
    }

    $qb->andWhere($expr);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}

#[Route(path: '/home', name: 'home', methods: ['GET'])]
public function home(MoviesRepository $subscriberRepository)
{

    $ids = ['0188324d-103f-79dc-b313-fe8f85b9aaf4','0188324d-103f-79dc-b313-fe8f8adb328c'];
    dd($subscriberRepository->fetchByUuids($ids));


}
```

[image]

Comment: It's pretty odd, to be honest; Doctrine supports UUIDs natively. What kind of database are you using?